# Auto save Interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex-19.1

iam using Oracle Apex version 19.1 to auto save an interactive grid using change dynamic action with the below code

Apex.region("static_id").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("save")
Iam getting an Uncaught typeerror: cannot read properties of null values error after saving one value how to resolve this issue any ideas?